# Javascript trigger on page load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this javascript that triggers update_cart when a quantity is changed...

```
    jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
        jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
    });
```

I am trying to modify it so that the trigger happens when the page loads instead, I have tried this...

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery("[name='update_cart']");
    });
```

But it is not working, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are not clicking anything in your second code block....

Comment: Your question is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You have determined that clicking the button on page load is the solution to the **real** problem, but in reality you are doing this to try and accomplish something else.  WHAT are you trying to accomplish, and WHY?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("[name='update_cart']").click();
});
```

Comment: That makes the page constantly refresh for some reason.  I wonder what the difference between the two methods are

Comment: WHY do you want this to happen when the page loads? The reason it constantly makes it reload is because clicking "Update Cart" *reloads the page*.  Then, when the page loads, you trigger the click again, which causes the page to reload.  Then when the page loads, you trigger the click again.  And so on....

Comment: I have a custom shipping rule that is time sensitive so I need WooCommerce to update the cart when the page first loads.  I found that script that updates the cart when quantity is changed but am trying to modify it now to work for my purposes